# Help understanding a concept in multiple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I am learning multiple integrals (Double and Triple Integral) and need help understanding a solution given in the book.

In first question, it is asked to find the area lying inside the circle $r=a\sin\theta$ and outside the cardioid $r=a(1-\cos\theta)$. using double integrals. In this question how do i find the range for $r$ for integration ?

Comment: Plot/make a sketch of both functions. From that you'll be able to see the range.

Comment: I have the sketch, but i am not able to make out for $r$. i think i don't know how to find the limits for $r$

Comment: I think you made a mistake: you are trying to find the area inside and outside the same function?

Comment: What is $a$ in this case?

Comment: @RonGordon Sorry !! I have corrected it

Comment: @rbm a is just any constant

Comment: Find the $\theta$ range first. The $r$-range will go from the "inner curve" to the "outer curve". (For a fixed $\theta$, draw a ray from the origin intersecting the region. You integrate over the portion of this ray that intersects the region.)

Comment: @DavidMitra ok, that was helpful, but in some question they have taken the r value from 0 to the given curve. like in this question-- Find area between the circle $r=2cos\theta$ and the line $x=rcos\theta$ [i.e x=y]

Comment: Well, in that case, the "inner curve" is always the origin.  Draw the picture, and imagine the region is swept out by a portion of the ray as it rotates counterclockwise. Keep track of the the innermost and outermost points of the portion.

Comment: @DavidMitra what does $r=0$ represent ?

Comment: Just the origin (the single point).

Comment: @DavidMitra That cleared it !! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the limits over $r$; rather, you need them over $\theta$.  The circle lies outside the cardioid when $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$; you can see this from a plot or by simply looking at the equations themselves.  The area you seek is then

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \int_{a(1-\cos{\theta})}^{a \sin{\theta}} dr \, r$$

I get as a result

$$\left ( 1-\frac{\pi}{4}\right ) a^2$$

Comment: ok, but in some question they have taken the r value from 0 to the given curve. like in this question-- Find area between the circle $r=2cos\theta$ and the line $x=rcos\theta$ [i.e x=y] ...should $r$ not vary from $2cos\theta$ to $rcos\theta$

Comment: @AmanMittal: I am not sure what you are saying.  In both cases, at $\theta=0$, $r=0$.  In any case, draw a picture; the integral over $r$ merely specifies where along the ray $\theta=\theta_0$ (i.e., some value of the polar angle) you are adding points up.  Here, the limits of the outer integral specify that we add points outside the cardioid, inside the circle.