# Find the area lying inside the circle $r=a \sin \theta$ and outside the cardioid $r=a(1-\cos \theta)$.

Tags: definite-integrals, area, polar-coordinates

I calculated this area to be:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{a(1- \cos\theta)}^{a \sin\theta} r \  \mathrm dr\ \mathrm d \theta=a^2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos\theta - \cos^2\theta \  \mathrm d \theta= a^2(1-\frac{\pi}{4}).$$

Just want to verify that my formulation and answer are correct since I do not have the correct answer myself.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Your question has actually been asked before here: [Help understanding a concept in multiple integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439868/help-understanding-a-concept-in-multiple-integrals).

Comment: Thanks @TobyMak! I did search for a similar question before posting but could not find it.